# Performance difference between table collations in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database-performance, collation

I know that having a different column collation impacts table performance, but I haven't been able to find any information on performance difference between table collations.

Also, what if I don't have any varchar/etc. type columns in my table, in that case does it even matter what collation is my table set to? If so what's the most robust collation to have for a table that contains only number column types?

Comment: The only way to know how this impacts you in your particular use case is to benchmark it. Remember, collation only applies to character columns, not binary, integer, or other types of data.

Comment: Do you know what collation is? Why would you even think that mixing collations makes a meaningful performance impact? You use collation for a REASON, and that reason is not performance.

Answer (score 3):

> The table character set and collation are used as default values for
>   column definitions if the column character set and collation are not
>   specified in individual column definitions. 
>   [from the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-table.html)

This suggests the choice would have absolutely no impact on the performance of a table lacking columns that have collation.
...and my guess is that even in tables that have fields with collation, the general performance impact on the table is minimal in queries not filtering/joining/grouping/etc... on those fields.