# Performance for Mysql JOINs on VARCHAR columns with different collation

Tags: mysql, collation

I could not easily find that information in the docs:

I started all my tables with **utf8_bin**, now I have one table with a column I would prefer to change to **utf8_mb4_900_as_ci** and consider utf8_mb4_900_ai_ci.

My question: Would this negatively affect JOINs with utf8_bin fields in terms of index use and performance ?

Comment: My understanding is the index performance would not be impacted. However the matching of records will be, depending on the actual data being joined. As one will be case-sensitive, another will be accent-sensitive and another that is neither. eg: `A <> a` vs `ü <> u` So `JOIN ON ü = u` will produce results for the `ai_ci` where `as_ci` and `bin` will not. Additionally considering utf8(mb3) vs utf8mb4, will also not be identical due to the extra characters that mb4 supports (non-BMP or supplemental characters stored with 4 bytes, where utf8_bin would support only 3 bytes).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Performance difference between table collations in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44954498/performance-difference-between-table-collations-in-mysql)

Comment: Voting to reopen because I think the 'closers' misinterpreted the question.

Comment: Please provide a specific example of the `SELECT` with the `JOIN` in question.  Also provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the two tables as they would look after the `ALTER`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your change leads to a `JOIN` between two columns with different `COLLATIONs`, performance may suffer *hugely*.

If both columns are exactly the same character set and collation, the `JOIN` can use an `INDEX` on one or the other column.

If the columns differ in `CHARACTER SET` (and hence `COLLATION`), then one column *may* be convertible to the other.

(Please provide a specific example.)

Comment: Previously my query did not use the indices it had for varchar on both sides. I have adjusted the collation and now execution plan shows Unique Key Lookup instead of Full Scan. And the performance indeed improved _hugely_. Thanks!